# NOT IN subquery gives 0 results

Tags: mysql, subquery

i'm not an mysqlologist but i have to deal with the following problem:

given a following table:

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+------+
| id    | articleID | img         | main |
+-------+-----------+-------------+------+
| 48350 |      4325 | scr426872xa |    1 |
| 48351 |      4325 | scr426872ih |    2 |
| 48352 |      4325 | scr426872jk |    2 |
| 48353 |      4326 | scr426882vs |    1 |
| 48354 |      4326 | scr426882ss |    2 |
| 48355 |      4326 | scr426882nf |    2 |
+-------+-----------+-------------+------+
```

each set of images of one distinct articleID should have one image set as main=1 and an unspecified number of images with main value of 2

Due to processing issues it can happen that there is no main=1 set for an image and i need to find the articleID where images with main=2 exist, but not with main=1. 
By explaining it backwards it is easier to fomulate what my thinking process for the query is. My idea was to create a result set (subquery) by querying the table for articleID where main is "1". Then use that result to check which distinct articleID of a query where main=2 is not in the results of aforementioned (sub-)query. Basically "substracting" all matching articleID lines. 
This should give basically the leftover of all main=2 lines which have no line with the same articleID where main=1

```
SELECT DISTINCT articleID 
FROM img_table WHERE main = 2 
AND articleID 
NOT IN (SELECT articleID FROM img_table WHERE main = 1 );
```

I get no result when I know for a fact that there are some. There is surely something I'm doing wrong. I hope my problem is explained in a way that not only me know what I want :)

Comment: result that you are getting using your query complies with the data that you have posted

Comment: what was the result you get

Comment: I think I understood maybe six words of that. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your problem description, it looks like you're actually looking for `NOT EXISTS` to check for rows that don't have a matching row in the subselect. Note that you do have to add the article id to the where clause in the subselect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT articleID 
FROM img_table t1
WHERE main = 2 
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT articleID 
   FROM img_table t2 
   WHERE main = 1 
   AND t2.articleID = t1.articleID);
```

I think your current solution should work too, but maybe you didn't show all the data. For the data you specified, the query would indeed return 0 rows, because all articleIDs have at least one main=1 and a main=2 image.

One important thing to remember: the subquery must not return any `NULL` value, otherwise `NOT IN` won't work properly. So if articleID is nullable, make sure your subselect looks like this:

```
(SELECT articleID FROM img_table WHERE main = 1 and articleID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as I was hoping to achieve with my query!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any issue in your query, Please add some data where article id having only main 2. Your query checking both article ID contains main 1,2. ie why you not getting any result.

Comment: The table i gave is an example, which is to show how it is supposed to be, i know my actual dB contains articleID which only have main=2 lines and no main=1. when i use my query given above i get no result lines back.